# How to cancel likes on other site

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

When you click the `Like` button `https://graph.facebook.com/object_id/likes` calls.
To cancel the `Like` what should I do?

I tried the following:

```
<code>
<script>
function doLike(objectId) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+objectId+'/likes',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
           access_token: '....'
       }
    });
}

function doCancel(objectId) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '???',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
           access_token: '....'
       }
    });
}
</script>

<input onclick="doLike('...')">Like</button>
<input onclick="doCancel('...')">Cancel</button>
</code>
```

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts. Firefox/Chrome and probably everything else apparently won't allow HTTP DELETE ajax calls unless the host has previously communicated during the current request. So `$.ajax{(type: 'delete', ... )}` works for YOUR server url host but not anything else.

The workaround is something like:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: "https://graph.facebook.com/" + FB_ACTION_ID,
  type: 'post',
  data: { access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
          'method': 'delete',
          '_method' : 'delete' }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an API which allows you to remove a Like of a Facebook page, this is not possible.

If you're looking for an API to remove a Like of an object (via URL) - you can make a HTTP DELETE request to `/LIKE_INSTANCE_ID` which is the ID returned to your app when you posted the [Open Graph like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/) - otherwise it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to "unlike" an object ID simply by doing a HTTP DELETE. Using your code, it'd look something like this:

```
function doCancel(objectId) {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+objectId+'/likes',
       type: 'delete',
       data: {
           access_token: '....'
       }
    });
}
```

Alternatively, use the Facebook Javascript SDK, in which you can simply do:

```
FB.api("/" + objectId + "/likes", 'delete', callback);
```

where callback is the function to call when the unlike operation is complete.